# To prove an inequality of degree 3 polynomilals

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, radicals

For $n\ge14$, I need to show that
$$(n-4)(n-2)\sqrt{n^2-10n+33}+n^2<(n-3)\sqrt{(n-2)^2+(n-3)^4}.$$
 How to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to prove that
$$(n-3)^3-n^2>(n-4)(n-2)\sqrt{n^2-10n+33},$$ which after squaring of  both sides gives
$$(2n-3)(n^4-24n^3+173n^2-476n+461)>0,$$ which is true because
$$n^4-24n^3+173n^2-476n+461=(n^2-12n-28)^2+85n(n-14)+42n-323>0.$$